# Apache Redirect 301 fails with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i try to do 301 redirect from this address:
`/web/8888/nsf/sbs.py?&_ID=9884&did=3025&PF=14&G=9884&SM=9884&lang=HE&_UserReference=956357C53FD2C8024C725EE5`

to this address:
`/?page=product&p_id=9884`

the 9884 value is dynamic value the others always not

I try to use:

```
Redirect 301 "/web/8888/nsf/sbs.py?&_ID=9884&did=3025&PF=14&G=9884&SM=9884&lang=HE&_UserReference=956357C53FD2C8024C725EE5"  /?page=product&p_id=9884
```

someone can help me solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does not examine query strings when performing a match. Instead, you'll need to use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to perform your redirections.

Keeping that in mind, from your example URL, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if the path part matches the URLs we want to redirect
# If so, check if the query string contains an ID
# If we find an ID, redirect to the correct product page with that ID number
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\A|&)_ID=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^web/8888/nsf/sbs\.py$ /?page=product&p_id=%2 [R=301,L]
```